# Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android, xml

My manifest gives me this error:

> Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>"

I have however opened and closed the activity tag as expected. I've also cleaned the project in an attempt to solve this problem but to no avail.
Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   `enter code here` package="com.TeamX.shuttle_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name = "com.TeamX.shuttle_App.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="21" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="21" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="21" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="21" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/shuttapplogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyA7SnyyG2IZ4flWaZelTOWKcrFVnsrLCck" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.TeamX.shuttle_app.ShuttleSplash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"> 

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

             <activity 
            android:name="com.TeamX.shuttle_App.Main" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

your

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.TeamX.shuttle_App.Main" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        </activity>
```

should be

```
 <activity 
        android:name="com.TeamX.shuttle_App.Main" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: I've done what you asked me to do but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.TeamX.shuttle_App.Main" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        </activity>
```

Do this:

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.TeamX.shuttle_App.Main" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```